# VBA Code not Filtering Report Properly

Tags: vba

To begin with I wasn't sure how to have a report open based off results from a user input and query. So I decided to try write my code for it:

```
Private Sub menuToReports_Click()

Dim crseFilter As String

'Asks for a course to filter report by
crseFilterQ:
crseFilter = InputBox("Enter a course", "Course Filter")

'If the response is null then returns to asking for filter
If crseFilter = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter one of the following: IB, IAL, AS, GCSE or     None")
GoTo crseFilterQ

'If reponse is none, then shows all students
ElseIf crseFilter = "None" Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Students", acViewReport

'Show whatever students are in the course that is specified in the response
Else
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Students", acViewReport, , Course = crseFilter

End If

End Sub
```

Whenever I run this code it and give it a response other than none, e.g. IB [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1oOX.png)

Ive tried a couple things already but can't seem to get it to work, so I turn to stack overflow. Please help! :p

Any help will be very much appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know if it will make a difference but the data type for the WhereCondition argument is variant - have you tried that instead of a string?

Comment: @Absinthe Hey, sorry for the delay, yea I tried that just now but still not working

Comment: Is this the issue? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-2010-sp1-reports-that-are-opened/65ac0657-94a5-4a8e-bad0-a95cc42dbd94

Comment: @Absinthe no, not the issue

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE CONDITION argument is not correct syntax. Since Course is a text type field:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "Students", acViewReport, , "Course = '" & crseFilter & "'"`